# #include workaround for Linqpad?

Tags: linqpad

I use Linqpad (thanks to `lprun`) as a general scripting tool; as a Unix guy who now works in a .net shop. it is my replacement for Python (albeit with type-safety). I know that, unfortunately, Linqpad doesn't support `#include` directives. I tried something like `cpp foo.linq | lprun -`, but `lprun` won't accept its script on `stdin`.

Is there a way to write slightly larger programs in Linqpad in a modular way? Creating a full-fledged Visual Studio project feels like overkill.

Comment: You can run other saved scripts using `LINQPad.Util.Run()` and even consume the results of the executed script to do more with it. Not sure if that's enough for you though.

Comment: That's good to know, though it doesn't let you share struct definitions.

Comment: This is no good workaround at present, but this feature is likely to be implemented in the (hopefully not too distant) future. I will post an answer here when that happens.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari - I am very much looking forward to this feature. I have way too much duplicate code at the moment.

Comment: for those interested, something like this is one of two features in the uservoice - https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/199744-make-it-possible-to-reference-and-execute-linq-fi or https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/211578-include-another-cs-file-s-in-a-linq-file